# rest api ubuntu 17.10 apache mod_rewrite .htaccess

Tags: apache2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just try and try and try ... I can't get a redirect to my index.php (restful api).

.htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I tried different configs, adding this or that to config files. Nothing works.
ubuntu:
    LSB Version:    ...
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
    Release:    17.10
    Codename:   artful

apache:

`Server version: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu)`

rewrite_module (shared) are enabled.

- Which config file do I have to edit?
- Do I have to put AllowOverride to the specific directory or does it propagate (for all subdirectories)?

Answer (score 0):

Another atempt worked. 
With this explanation https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04
I could set up the  000-default.conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available correctly. 
Restart apache2 don't just reload.